# simple adding up value in windows forms ASP.NET trough button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml

i have a problem where when i try to add a value trough the click_button event, the value will remain the same, could someone help me out with this?

```
   int parallelgroepnummer = 0;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox1.Checked = false;
        checkparallel = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkparallel == true)
        {

            {


                parallelgroepen.Add(parallelgroepnummer, "test");
                parallelgroepnummer = parallelgroepnummer + 1;
                ListBox1.Items.Add("parallele groep " + parallelgroepnummer);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add("notparallel");
        }
    }

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkparallel == false)
        {
            checkparallel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            checkparallel = false;
        }
    }
```

the answer always returns 1 here.

Comment: if you button click event performs a post, which i assume since you are in a page. your number variable gets set to 0 again. thats why it stays 1

Comment: i found what the problem was, i should have added static to the parallelgroepnummer variable.

Comment: just write it in an answer, stackoverflow allows and encourages that ^^

Comment: Why did you tag this as `xaml`?

Comment: i orginially wanted to add the xaml file, but got an error that there was too much code, after which i forgot to remove the xaml tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int parallelgroepnummer = 0;
```

change in:

```
private static int parallelgroepnummer = 0;
```